# Using the Google Visualization API to call a RegEx to be used in a Jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, google-visualization

What I'm attempting to do is to use Google visualization api to query a spreadsheet and return a regex to an input field called `terms_out`. I'd then like Jquery to validate my form using this returned regex value.

Using the following code, I've been able to validate my form ONLY when the value of `terms_out` is defined in html. Ex. `value="^[0-9]+$"`

```
<input id="terms_out" class="terms_out" name="terms_out" value="^[0-9]+$"/>
  <form id="Form">
    <input id='summary' name="summary" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
  </form> 

<script>
$(function() {
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, RegEx) {return RegEx.test(value); }, "Not Valid!");    

$("#Form").validate({
   rules: {
       summary: {
           required: true,
           regex: new RegExp($("#terms_out").val())
       }
   }
});
});
</script>
```

If the value for the input field `terms_out` is undefined `value=""` the form validates upon clicking submit as long as something is typed into the `summary` field.

I tried using a variable called `keyterms` to store the called value of `terms_out` but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work...or if I'm even on the right rack.

Here's the html of what I'm trying...

```
<input id="terms_out" class="terms_out" name="terms_out" value=""/>
<form id="Form">
<input id='summary' name="summary" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

And here's the full js...

```
/*Google Visualization api */
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(GetTerms);

function GetTerms() {
var queryTerms = new
google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1OE_9A-oeboj2XxAGDoz5o3q4vbGUDy4bDVajBFG1l1U&sheet=WR4');

queryTerms.send(handleQueryTermsResponse);
}

function handleQueryTermsResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in ID Validation Query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

var datatable2 = response.getDataTable();   
var terms = datatable2.getValue(1,7);    
    document.getElementById('terms_out').value = terms;

    }

/*Jquery Validator */
$(document).ready(function () {
$.validator.addMethod('regex', function(value, element, RegEx) {          
 return RegEx.test(value);
}, "Not Valid!");    

var keyterms = document.getElementsById("terms_out")[0].val;

$("#Form").validate({

rules: {
       summary: {
          required: true,
         regex: new RegExp(keyterms)
        } 
    }
 });
 });
```

I'm very new at this so please excuse my ignorance. I've been struggling with this for the past few days, so I'd greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I figured it out. Jquery was trying to validate before the terms_out input had a value. All I had to do is wrap the validation in a function and call it on submit. Like this...

```
<input id="terms_out" type="text" class="terms_out" name="terms_out" value=""/>

<form id="Form">
<input id='summary' name="summary" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="changevalue()"/>
</form>



<script>
function changevalue() {

$.validator.addMethod('regex', function(value, element, RegEx) {          
 return RegEx.test(value);
}, "Not Valid!");    

$("#Form").validate({

rules: {
       summary: {
          required: true,
         regex: new RegExp($("#terms_out").val())
            } 
        }
     });
}
</script>
```